# What Prettier rule is breaking this JSX into multiple lines?

Tags: prettier

I'm wondering what Prettier rule or rules is or are causing this code:

[image]

To be formatted as such:

[image]

The "problem" in ESLint (I'm using `eslint-plugin-prettier` and `eslint-config-prettier`, although disabling ESLint and only using Prettier produces the same result) is displayed as such:

```
Replace `(<a·key='draft'·href={'/draft/'·+·results['id']}>Draft</a>))` with `⏎················<a·key="draft"·href={'/draft/'·+·results['id']}>⏎··················Draft⏎················</a>,⏎··············);`eslintprettier/prettier
```

Which led me to believe that possibly this was being cause by `printWidth`, but I've currently set that to `600` to experiment, and this line has been unaffected—other lines have so I've ruled out that `printWidth` is not being respected. Here is my `.prettierrc.json`:

```
{
  "bracketSpacing": false,
  "jsxBracketSameLine": true,
  "singleQuote": true,
  "trailingComma": "all",
  "printWidth": 600
}
```

It seems like some of Prettier's more arcane rules are being applied here, and maybe I'm seeing the confluence of a couple of things. Maybe there's some preference for JSX that's also an argument to a function?

Comment: Please clarify your problem. Are you having trouble with making Prettier and ESLint play well together? Or do you just want to learn why Prettier works the way it does? Note that Prettier is an opinionated tool and doesn't have 'rules' (at least not in the sense that ESLint and other linters use for this term).

Comment: @thorn̈ the later. I'm realizing that I haven't fully appreciated the difference between "rules" in the ESLint sense and Prettier's fuzzier application of "opinions." I was originally wondering if there was a way to modify the behavior I mentioned in the original post, but I get the sense that doing that would be pretty involved. For what it's worth, I "agree" with what it's done to the mentioned code, but others I work with were wondering if we could tune it somehow.

Comment: 'Opinionated' in this case essentially stands for 'intentionally non-customizable', so no, this can't be tweaked.

Comment: Great, thanks for helping me through that!